# Test failure 7% for HTTP Call out

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock, invocable-method

I am not sure why I am getting the two errors I labeled below during the http send in the first class or in the Mock Impl class when I assert the endpoint.

```
public class ProcessHandlerShowAccounts 
{
    static HttpResponse res;

    public class AccountParameter
    {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public Id accountId;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String name;
    }


    @InvocableMethod
    public static void handleNewAccounts(AccountParameter [] accountParameters) 
    {


 webServiceCallOut(accountParameters[0].accountId,accountParameters[0].name);

    }  
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void webServiceCallOut(ID n, String a){

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        //HTTPResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setEndpoint('https://example.Accounts'+'?sfdcid='+n+'&operation='+a);

        String username = 'ic';
        String password ='123';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setMethod('POST');


        try{
                   //error on line below, for the call out
                res = http.send(req);

            if(res.getStatus()=='200')
            {
            System.debug('GET BODY: '+ res.getBody());
            }
            else{
                System.debug('GET Status Else: '+res.getStatus());
            }
        }catch(System.CalloutException e){
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }  
    }    
}
```

TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
public class ProcessHandlerShowAccountsTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ProcessHandlerShowAccountsMockImpl());

        // Call method to test.
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
            Test.startTest();

 ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.webServiceCallOut('0011B000021QvM5','create');
        Test.stopTest();
        // Verify response received contains fake values
        String contentType = ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"example":"test"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.res.getStatusCode());

    }
}
```

MOCK IMPL

```
@isTest
global class ProcessHandlerShowAccountsMockImpl implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        //ERROR on Line Below
        System.assertEquals('https://example.Accounts', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return ProcessHandlerShowAccounts.res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the actual texts of the errors you receive?

Comment: @David Reed. Within the developer console, I run the test and it says Success and when I go to the test section it tells me the location of the errors and 7% pass but no detail/explanation . I have labeled in the code above the locations of the errors.

Comment: You can access test failure details by double clicking on a line item in the Tests panel to load the full run results, including the specific errors thrown.

Comment: @David Reed Error: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: http://example.com/example/test, Actual: https://example/integration/flowapi/_SFDC/v01/Accounts?sfdcid=0011B000021QvM5QAK&operation=create

Comment: OK, I expected the assertion failure. What's the other error?

Comment: On the error that is all that is listed. but gives me the two lines I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mock appears to me to be correctly implemented, at a glance. The issue is that your assertion is failing, and it's failing for a pretty comprehensible reason.

In your class that performs the callout, you do

```
req.setEndpoint('https://example.Accounts'+'?sfdcid='+n+'&operation='+a);
```

but then in your mock class, you perform the following assertion:

```
System.assertEquals('https://example.Accounts', req.getEndpoint());
```

The actual error text you receive has some differences in the URLs from your code (presumably you stripped out identifying details), but the root of it appears to simply be that you're setting the endpoint to one thing and then asserting it to be equal to another.

Since you're doing some dynamic generation of the endpoint, your assertions should take that into account. For example, you might `System.assert(req.getEndpoint.startsWith(STANDARD_ENDPOINT))`, to show that the first portion is correct. You might then further decompose the endpoint string to pull out the dynamic parameters `sfdcid` and `operation` and assert they have the values you expect them to have based upon your test call.

Whenever you have a "mysterious" assertion error, it can be useful to `System.debug()` the values that are involved. In many cases, these failures stem from little more than a typo or a misunderstanding of how the system will format a value (rather than a true failure). Seeing the actual values can guide you to the logical issue in your code.

It's worth noting that you may be setting yourself up for confusion by naming an HTTP callout "web service". In Salesforce, that usually refers to a SOAP/XML callout.

Comment: Thanks so could i just copy and paste and set the dynamic parameters as static variables?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: so I matched both urls and I am still getting the same assertion error

Comment: Use `System.debug()` to see what values you're actually getting. `System.assertEquals()` is pretty simple. The values are either equal or they are not, and it's telling you they are not. You need to find out why.

Comment: the values are coming up null, so the values that I append to the url I made them static.  So that I could use them in the mock impl class.  Still coming up null.

Comment: I would make them instance variables in the mock class. You may be trying to cross transaction boundaries with the statics, which won't work.

Comment: could you give me an example of implementing an instance variable